# Image alignment error

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have two images, one of which is misaligned. I need to align the images. So I calculate feature points using `SURF`, match them using `BFMatcher`, find homography and then apply `warpPerspective`. Here is my [code](http://goo.gl/TcwWLq)

For these inputs :[input1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1PxR.png),[input2](http://imgur.com/DXiKlaF), I am getting a very distorted [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUIAb.png).

I am probably doing something obviously wrong. Any points?

Comment: There seems to be only one input image.

Comment: Added the second image in EDIT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I suspect that you should swap trainIdx and queryIdx.

And try to draw matches, in my experiments, they are rather random.

For quick test try use the same image, or transform a little bit first image and use it as the second one.

Comment: This worked!! Swapping the train and query index did the trick. Thanks